Compose: Remove extra whitespace when using Text with LineBreak
font size: 40.sp

What I want: No extra whitespace at the end of the first line

That whitespace causes the Text composable to be wider than it should be, and thus, when trying to center this, the text looks misaligned.
Text(
            text = text,
            style = textStyle.copy(lineBreak = LineBreak.Paragraph),
            fontSize = 40.sp,
            modifier = modifier,
        )


Read this blog it's help you https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/fixing-font-padding-in-compose-text-768cd232425b
